# Ng-table access to nested fields while grouping

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I'm trying grouping by nested field, but groupBy doesn't work,it works only by primary fields.

```js
$scope.groupby = ' ';
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,
    count: 10,
    sorting: {
        name: 'asc'
    }
}, {
    total: function () {
        return $scope.alert.length;
    },
    groupBy: 'alertRuleCategory.name',
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
        var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.alert, $scope.tableParams.orderBy()) : $scope.alert;
        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
    }
});
```

Sample of alert element

```js
{
    name: 'hello',
    alertRuleCategory: {
        id: 1;name: 'test'
    },
    id: 5
};
```

Can you help me, to find some workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function for groupBy. Passing your alert object into the groupBy function allows you to access its deep properties.

```
groupBy: function (alert) {
  return alert.alertRuleCategory.name;
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NsMAcEKokwFRGCBdvTdz?p=preview)